# A question on the Dedekind Psi function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This question is inspired by this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370921/additive-number-theory-hilbert-spaces-and-polynomial-rings by changing the sum of divisors function $\sigma$ with the Dedekind function $\Psi$.

The Dedekind function is defined as:

$$\Psi(n) = n \prod_{p|n}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{p} \right)} $$

Let

$$h_n = |\{ k | 1 \le k \le n, \Psi(l) \neq k \forall l\}|$$

Is it true that:

$$h_n = n-1-\Pi(n-1)$$

where $\Pi$ is the prime pi function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the case. If we define $g_n = n - 1 - \Pi(n-1)$, then we have
$$g_{36} = g_{35} + 1$$
since $\Pi(35) = \Pi(34)$, but since $36 = \Psi(27)$ we have $h_{36} = h_{35}$. Hence $g_n \neq h_n$ holds for at least one of $n = 35$ and $n = 36$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I was obviously too fast when typing this.